# I want a dot before my titleentry in toc using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I like a dot before my section-entry in the table of contents. When I apply the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` line in the code below the dot also disappears.

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}  % this line causes the trouble. removes the
                                % sectionnumber (which is good) but also removes
                                % the dot (which is not)..
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{15mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnumb}{$\cdot$ }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Welkom]{Welkom en tot ziens}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Redefine `\cftsecfont` instead of `\cftsecaftersnumb`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{15mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries$\cdot$~~}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Welkom]{Welkom en tot ziens}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved my problem.. Thanx..

Comment: @Gerco-Kees You're welcome -- and don't forget to upvote and accept my answer. ;-)